# "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown" after calling Fill method

Tags: c#, dataset, dataadapter

I am trying to make a report with a dataset to bring, possibly, more than 300000 records from a SQL Server Database. But it gives me the following error:

`Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown`

```
ClaimDS ds = new ClaimDS();
sp_CustomForms_UCAF_SummaryTableAdapter adapt = new   sp_CustomForms_UCAF_SummaryTableAdapter();

adapt.Fill(ds.sp_CustomForms_UCAF_Summary, x.amID,0,0,0,_fromdate,_todate,0);
ds.Dispose();
ds.Clear();
```

This error appears directly after `adapt.Fill(ds.sp_CustomForms_UCAF_Summary, x.amID,0,0,0,_fromdate,_todate,0);` has been called.

Comment: Have you tried in the stored procedure limiting the rows as a test, like SELECT TOP 100 * FROM <table> to see if you still get the error.

Comment: the code doesn't make a lot of sense.  After filling the dataset you are disposing the data.  You also can't clear a dataset after you dispose the object.  Remove the Clear statement and try again.

Comment: tnank you .. as you advise me its working if i use select top 100 but if i select all this problem happen again .